# Build Android LatinIME

Tags: android, build, ime

I want to do some changes on the LatinIME.
Therefore I cloned this Repo [LatinIME](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/) and have done them.

Now I noticed that I need to build this within the AOSP cause there are dependencies.

My problem is now that I only want to build the LatinIME (with dependencies), but without building and cloning the whole AOSP.

I don't want to download and build the whole AOSP, like described [here](http://source.android.com/source/building.html).

Is there any way to do this?

**Edit**: I found the following solutions.

1. Build within AOSP and build the particular module with `mmm` macro. (This builds only the module and it's dependencies.)
2. Build with app toolchain and use prebuilt libraries extracted from prebuilt AOSP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following solutions.

1. Build within AOSP and build the particular module with `mmm` macro. (This builds only the module and it's dependencies.)
2. Build with app toolchain and use prebuilt libraries extracted from prebuilt AOSP.

Answer (score -1):

Just clone this and build your own:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/+/master/java/

Comment: can you be more clear about your instructions? I don't understand it.